# openGL texture mapping - no details, why?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to apply texture mapping to a sphere I draw.
I am able to apply my texture to it. But I don't see any of the details of my image. I only see an orange sphere, no details.

This is my image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdY1H.jpg
my image is a 17x17 24bit bmp.

[image]

I just see a green sphere. Why please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzp0b.jpg

My code:

```
void glWidget::myTextureMapping()
 {
    QImage t;
    QImage b;
    if(!b.load("...sun2.bmp"))
    {
       qDebug("error with image\n");
    }

    t = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat( b );
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture[0] );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D,3 ,17,17, GL_RGB,GL_BITMAP, t.bits());

 }

 void glWidget::drawSphere()
 {
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    glPushMatrix();
   glScalef(1,1,1);
   glLoadIdentity();
   GLUquadricObj *quadric=gluNewQuadric();
   gluQuadricNormals(quadric, GLU_SMOOTH);
   gluSphere(quadric, 0.25, 360,360);
   gluDeleteQuadric(quadric);
   glPopMatrix();
  }

 void glWidget::initializeGL()
{
   myTextureMapping();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                            // Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);               // Black Background
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                                 // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the generation of texture coordinates ,before you draw the sphere by using the following function:

```
gluQuadricTexture(quadric, GLU_TRUE);
```

The generation of texture coordinates is disabled by default.

See [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluQuadricTexture.xml)

Comment: Hello, I added this line. But it didn't solve my issue, I think..
this is what I get now: http://imgur.com/tHppEjO

Comment: Well. Mapping a 2D rectangle to a sphere is impossible to do without introducing some distortions. YOo must of course create the texture to match the mapping in use. Since you rely on glu here, you must adhere to the mapping it provides, which is [explained on the manpage](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluSphere.xml).

Comment: Indeed I was thinking something similar. But could u give me some advice about how I could introduce this distortion? Or what are the other possibilities?